# What is the difference between an operator and a function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax

I am new to Haskell and this mixture of Infix and Prefix notation is confusing me.
What is the difference between an operator like '+' and a function like head? How do I write an operator 'c' which does this 1 c 1 = 2?

I found this definition a ! b = True. How does Haskell know that I am defining ! and not a function a?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Haskell, to create an operator you must use the following "operator symbols":

! # $ % * +  . / < = > ? \ ^ | : - ~

So, for example

```
($$$) a b = a+b
```

Defines an operator $$$ which can be used in the expression 1 $$$ 1 to yield a value of 2.

Conceptually, there is no difference between an operator and a function, and you can use backticks or parens to make one work like the other.

**EDIT:**

Just so it is 100% clear, let me demonstrate turning a function into an operator and vice versa:

For the operator '+', the following two expressions are equivalent:

```
1+1
(+) 1 1
```

Similarly, for a function, the following two expressions are equivalent:

```
foo 1 2
1 `foo` 2
```

Comment: You can also define operators and functions using infix syntax too. `a $$$ b = a + b` and `a \`foo\` b = a + b` both work as definitions for example. (Ack! There shouldn't be a space after foo and the following backquote.)

Comment: trinithis: Yep, you're right. I thought about that but forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 6):

Haskell knows you aren't defining a function called `a` because the `!` wouldn't be valid in a function argument list. In order to use the `!` not as an operator but just as a normal identifier, you need to enclose it in parentheses. If you wrote instead `a (!) b = True`, then it would define the function `a :: t -> t1 -> Bool`.

This is the entire difference between operators and normal identifiers in Haskell — there are special syntax rules for operators that allow them to be used infix without backticks. Otherwise, they're just functions.

Answer (score 5):

Really, the only difference is syntax. Function names begin with a lower-case letter, followed by a series of alpha-numeric characters. Operators are some unique sequence of the typical operator characters (+ - / * < > etc.).

Functions can be used as operators (in-fix) by enclosing the function name in ` characters. For example:

```
b = x `elem` xs -- b is True if x is an element in xs.
```

Operators can be used as functions (pre-fix) by enclosing the operator in parens. For example:

```
n = (+) 2 5 -- n = 2 + 5, or 7.
```