# type definitions on functions

Tags: haskell

```hs
orderedq f [] = True
orderedq f (x:[]) = True
orderedq f (x:y:zs) = and [(f x y), (orderedq f zs)]

num_orderedq xs = orderedq <= xs
```

`ghci` says, when trying to load using `:l [file name]` says:

```hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( route-combinations.hs, interpreted )

route-combinations.hs:9:1: error:
    * Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Ord ((t -> t -> Bool) -> [t] -> Bool)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * When checking the inferred type
        num_orderedq :: forall t.
                        Ord ((t -> t -> Bool) -> [t] -> Bool) =>
                        ((t -> t -> Bool) -> [t] -> Bool) -> Bool
  |
9 | num_orderedq xs = orderedq <= xs
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Is my typing wrong?

What is the correct type signature for the code? It doesn't accept this:

```hs
orderedq :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
orderedq f [] = True
orderedq f (x:[]) = True
orderedq f (x:y:zs) = and [(f x y), (orderedq f zs)]

num_orderedq :: [a] -> Bool
num_orderedq xs = orderedq <= xs
```

Comment: `orderedq` is a function, so this can not be "smaller" than `xs`.

Comment: So the problem is *not* with the signature. Haskell can automatically derive most signatures, the problem is with the fact that you compare a function with a list of elements.

Comment: What do you mean by smaller? Are you refering to the line containing `num_orderedq xs = orderedq <= xs`? I am trying to pass `<=` and `xs` as arguments.

If the problem is that `<=` is being assumed to be an infix function, how can I know that this is the case with functions in the future, and pass that function to another function?

Answer (score 4):

You said that your intention with the line

```hs
num_orderedq xs = orderedq <= xs
```

was to pass two arguments to `orderedq`: the `<=` function and `xs`. Syntactically, though, you need to enclose an operator in parentheses when you’re using it in this context:

```hs
num_orderedq xs = orderedq (<=) xs
```

Operators and functions are semantically the same thing in Haskell; the only difference is their syntax. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2480974/371228) and its answers for more on the differences between operators and other functions.

Answer (score 3):

If you write `orderedq <= xs`, then this is interpreted as `(<=) orderedq xs`, with [**`(<=) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--61-) a comparison to check if the left operand is less than or equal to the right operand.

It thus aims to compare `orderedq` with `xs`. But this is not possible, since `orderedq` is a function, and regardless what `xs` is, normally functions are not ordered (no instance of `Ord`).

If you want to pass the `(<=)` function, you can write:

```
num_orderedq :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
num_orderedq = orderedq (<=)
```

Note that your `orderedq` can be rewritten to:

```
orderedq :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
orderedq f [] = True
orderedq f xa@(_:xs) = and (zipWith f xa xs)
```

Comment: Should it be rewritten to
```haskell
orderedq f [] = True
orderedq f xa@(_:xs) = all (zipWith f xa xs)
```
?

Comment: @SultanLegend: no, that part was correct, but often one makes use of higher-order functions to reduce the amount of code, and explicit recursion.

Comment: Where in the documentation can I learn more about this syntax `xa@(_:xs)`?

Comment: @SultanLegend: that is an *as pattern*: https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html

Comment: @SultanLegend The part `orderedq f xa@(_:xs) = and (zipWith f xa xs)` is equivalent to `orderedq f (x:xs) = and (zipWith f (x:xs) xs)`, which does not use the as-pattern. The `xa@(....)` as-pattern is only a convenient way to give a name to the whole `x:xs`.